# How does gcc find the following header file?

Tags: linux, gcc

I've included `sys/ptrace.h` into my C program.

The output of `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 -v` gives the following paths where gcc looks for header files

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

output of `gcc -M` for my program gives the following header file locations

```
    pt.o: pt.c /usr/include/stdc-predef.h /usr/include/stdio.h \
 /usr/include/features.h /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h /usr/include/libio.h \
 /usr/include/_G_config.h /usr/include/wchar.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stdarg.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio_lim.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/sys_errlist.h \
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ptrace.h
```

Since `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is not contained in the first output, how does gcc find `sys/ptrace.h`?

EDIT:

The output of `echo '#include <sys/ptrace.h>' | gcc -fsyntax-only -xc -v -H -` results in

```
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
```

Comment: It is recursively looking at `/usr/include`..  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It doesn't look like it recursively looks through. If it did, there would be no need to include the sys/ prefix. Including just ptrace.h, for example, does not work.

Comment: I don't think you included `/sys/ptrace.h` but `sys/ptrace.h`, right?

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in the "multiarch" patches to GCC. The directory `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` *is* being treated as a system include directory and *should* be included in the search-path list printed by `gcc -v`.  I am not sure how someone managed to achieve that bug; if I remember correctly, the most obvious way to add system include directories does add them to what is printed by `-v`.  (I wrote ~50% of GCC's preprocessor, but that was 15 years ago, so I may be misremembering something.)

Comment: @Ramhound It most definitely does *not* recursively search below `/usr/include`.  That would break just about every C library in the world.

Comment: @user912083132 Hm, come to think of it, there's another possibility.  Do you get a different search list printout if you do `echo '#include <sys/ptrace.h>' | gcc -fsyntax-only -xc -v -H -` ?  The program `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1` is not meant to be used directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Shorter answer.

Your question is about the output of `cc1 -v`, but that doesn’t factor in the CPP (C Pre-Processor) and it’s includes that are mixed into the whole compilation chain. If you run `cpp -v` on your system you should see, a mix of includes that looks similar to the output of `cc1 -v` but with at least the `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` path added in there.

#### Longer answer.

> Since `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is not contained in the first
>   output, how does gcc find `sys/ptrace.h`?

Technically, `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` is not explicitly set in the first output, but `/usr/include/` definitely is. And that is a default search path [as explained in the official GNU GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html):

> GCC looks in several different places for headers. On a normal Unix
>   system, if you do not instruct it otherwise, it will look for headers
>   requested with `#include <file>` in:
>
> - /usr/local/include
> - libdir/gcc/target/version/include
> - /usr/target/include
> - /usr/include

And further explained here:

> GCC looks for headers requested with `#include "file"` first in the
>   directory containing the current file, then in the directories as
>   specified by `-iquote` options, then in the same places it would have
>   looked for a header requested with angle brackets. For example, if
>   `/usr/include/sys/stat.h` contains #`include "types.h"`, GCC looks for
>   `types.h` first in `/usr/include/sys`, then in its usual search path.

So this implies that the `x86_64-linux-gnu/` path is simply inserted into `/usr/include/*/sys/` like this:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ptrace.h
```

At least that is what I initially thought in [an earlier version of this question](https://superuser.com/revisions/981788/2). But [after checking out this site](http://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art026) the explanation of what is happening is a bit more detailed and the direct response from that site to the equivalent content to what I posted above is reposted below; bold emphasis is mine:

> but that's sort of a wishy-washy answer (and also incomplete). Surely
>   there must be a way to get GCC to tell you exactly where it's going to
>   end up looking for its header files? **Well, although it's convenient
>   to think of GCC as a single monolithic application that takes in
>   source code files and spits out working programs, it's technically a
>   collection of other programs which chain together to produce the final
>   compiled object file. The first of these is CPP, short for *C
>   Pre-Processor*, whose job is to look for compiler directives like
>   `#include` and modify the source code as specified by them; in the case of include, by copying the contents of another file into the current
>   one.** You can see where it looks for these files by passing it the -v
>   flag:

Know that the CPP (C Pre-Processor) is the first step in the compiler’s process, let’s look at the “include” output of `cpp -v` on my Ubuntu 12.04.5 testing system:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

In there you can clearly see `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`. And to compare, here is the similar “include” output of `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1 -v` on the same Ubuntu 12.04.5 testing system:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include
```

Note how `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` is clearly inserted into the mix by the initial CPP (C Pre-Processor) action. And the post on that site goes on further to explain where those paths come from; again bold emphasis is mine:

> **this path is actually built into CPP (which is part of GCC) at compile time; if for whatever reason you end up deleting one of those
>   directories, it will still be checked for on each compile.** Each
>   directory is searched in the order it's listed here; if a file is
>   found in `/usr/local/include`, the next three directories won't be
>   checked.

So it all boils down to the CPP (C Pre-Processor) being called as the first part of a C compilation chain.

Comment: Why does x86_64-linux-gnu/ get shoved into the middle?

Comment: @user912083132: That's the `$TARGET` part I mentioned in my answer and comment. It's the output of `config.guess` when GCC was compiled, or which was given to its `configure` script with the `--target` flag. The real question is, how does that path get assembled? Does it just go back through the same list, appending `$TARGET` to each, after failing to find the header the first time through?

Answer (score 2):

Short of delving into the GCC source code, I can't give you a "why", but I can tell you that the version of GCC I have here falls back to `/usr/include/$TARGET` after exhausting the choices you [and Giacomo1968 have found](https://superuser.com/a/981788/167207). You can see it like so:

```
$ strace -f -e open gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o 2>&1 | grep ptrace.h
```

where `foo.c` contains a `#include <sys/ptrace.h>`.

You need the `-f` argument here because `gcc` spawns children to do the actual compilation work. You need the `2>&1` because `strace` is writing its results to stderr, not stdout.

Notice you get `ENOENT` errors for all of the documented directories before it finally tries the one that succeeds.